# Different way of declaring theme in android

Tags: android, themes, android-styles

I am confused in declaring `theme` in `style.xml`. In some **project** 
I see `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` and in some places `Themes` are **declared** without @android:style like

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

> How could I know which way to use. And in which case One is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Is the same. Since API 21 there is no need to reference it as resource to inherit from parent.